# How to modify font of some text in React app page?

Tags: reactjs

I'm DevOps by trade but learning some development on my own. I built a basic ToDo app use ReactJs. Now I'm taking small steps to tweak it here and there - for example, offloaded from local mysql DB to AWS RDS-hosted Db.

I want to modify the font of the app name, "HoneyDo". How do I change the font of just a single piece of text? I've done my own research - while there is a lot of material out there regarding React and fonts, I can't figure out to do this for my use case. My App.js document is below:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import AddTask from "./components/add-task.component";
import Task from "./components/task.component";
import TasksList from "./components/tasks-list.component";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary">
                    <Link to={"/tasks"} className="navbar-brand">
                        HoneyDo
                    </Link>
                    <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/tasks"} className="nav-link">
                                Tasks
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <Link to={"/add"} className="nav-link">
                                Add
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div className="container mt-3">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={["/", "/tasks"]} component={TasksList} />
                        <Route exact path="/add" component={AddTask} />
                        <Route path="/tasks/:id" component={Task} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The specific line is here:

```
<Link to={"/tasks"} className="navbar-brand">
                            HoneyDo
                        </Link>
```

How can I change the font of this one line of text?

Answer (score 1):

This one should be the easiest way to go:
Add your CSS underneath Bootstrap's CSS:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./mycssfile.css"
```

Add your font in your file:

```
# In mycssfile.css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```